# Defining a NuSOAP server within a class definition

Tags: php, nusoap

Pretty simple. Due to the requirements of my project, I have to create a NuSOAP server within a class definition. I cannot get it to work. I get a fault back with this error message: "error in msg parsing: xml was empty, didn't parse!" What do I need to make this work?

This is the code that is common to both approaches:

```
require_once('/xxx/nusoap/nusoap.php');

function SomeMethod(
    $someParameter
) {
    return "Success: $someParameter!";
}

function registerSomeMethod() {
    $in = array();
    $in['someParameter'] = 'xsd:string';

    $out = array();
    $out['return'] = 'xsd:string';

    $this->_server->register("SomeMethod",$in,$out,$this->_namespace,"SomeMethod","rpc","encoded");
}
```

Adding this code at the global level produces a functioning Web service:

```
$namespace = 'uri:mycompany'; 

$server = new soap_server;
$server->configureWSDL('mycompany',$namespace);

registerSomeMethod(); 

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Wrapping that code in a class definition as below produces a Web service that will return WSDL directly to the browser but responds to client calls with a SoapFault "error in msg parsing: xml was empty, didn't parse!"

```
class MyService {

    public function __construct() {

        $namespace = 'uri:mycompany'; 

        $server = new soap_server;
        $server->configureWSDL('mycompany',$namespace);

        registerSomeMethod(); 

        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
        $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

    }

} // class

$o = new MyService;
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix that change this:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

for this:

```
$this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: with respect to sample code.

$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Put "global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;" in __construct(). I'm new to PHP and completely overlooked that detail.